# Why Layout with <layout> tag doesn't work correctly with BottomSheetBehavior?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, bottom-sheet

I'm trying to build layout contain a `bottom_sheet` and I have this simple example:

```
 <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_layout" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And I'm using `data-binding` inside my *BottomSheetDialogFragment(bottom_sheet_layout)* like below:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    //.... content

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The problem is that the `app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"` attribute doesn't work, the `bottom_sheet_layout` appear without any influence from this attribute.

Everything work fine if I replace `<layout>` with some other layout like `LinearLayout`

Comment: because you can't use `app:behavior_peekHeight` in the layout section

Comment: @BurhanKhanzada why?

Comment: because of it is attribute for `bottomsheetbehaviour`, not for layout binding tag